# How can I find a path to a running application on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I am using Mac OS Catalina (10.15.4) and am looking at a running GUI application. I want to find out exactly what path that application is running from. How can I do this?

Comment: Can't you get that from the Menu bar, from Help, or File / About this app?

Comment: No, that does not have the information I need (the file path).

Comment: If you select it in your /Applications folder and press Command-i, you should get the information you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command-click on any GUI app's icon in the Dock and it will be revealed in the Finder.

The actual executable binary file is inside the `.app` bundle that was revealed, and is usually named the same as the app (without the `.app` ending this time), so `Example.app/Contents/MacOS/Example`.